# Generating Dynamic TextBoxes and Labels

Tags: c#

I want to generate dynamic textBoxes and labels as i add columns in my datagridview in C#.
I also wish to write a SQL query later which takes my newly generated textBoxes as arguments/new column names. The error that occurs says 'Argument out of range exception was unhandled'.

Please help

```
public void CreateLabels()
    {
        Label lb = new Label();
        this.Controls.Add(lb);
        int p= dataGridView1.ColumnCount;
        for (int k = p; k <= dataGridView1.ColumnCount; k++)
        {
            for (int z =p; z <= dataGridView1.ColumnCount; z++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Refresh();
                lb.Text = dataGridView1.Columns[z++].HeaderText;
            }
            lb.Show();
            lb.Visible = true;
        }
        lb.Location = new Point(m,n=n+25);
        lb.Width = 199;
        lb.Height = 20;
    }
    public void CreateTextBoxes()
    {
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        this.Controls.Add(tb);
        for (int i = 5; i <= dataGridView1.ColumnCount; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Refresh();
            tb.Name = "textBox" + i;
            MessageBox.Show(tb.Name);
        }
        tb.Location = new Point(x, y = y + 25);
        tb.Show();
        tb.Visible = true;         
    }*/

    //Below  method is used to get data in datagridview1 and to reflect in runtime text boxes and labels;the visible property is kept false 

    /*private void displayRec()
    {
        try
        {
            string str = System.Environment.MachineName;
            SqlConnection sconn = new SqlConnection("Data Source='" + str + "';Initial Catalog=main;Integrated Security=True");
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from invent", sconn);
            da.Fill(dt);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
            //dataGridView1.Refresh();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you can show us some code..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest I don't understand the idea of your loops. They have same condition and you never use the 'k';
However both of the loops are starting at the last column +1; and in the assignment of lb.Text you are trying to get the HeaderText of the column that does not exist. This is why you have out of range exception.

Comment: @user2038924 welcome, I think you better to revise your code, inside of your loops you're assigning results to the text property of the same lable you've created at the beginning of the function, and afterwards you're showing it and making it visible again and again...